# Log Off Windows Users Remotely by User Name (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and I apologize in advance if my question is rhetorical.
I want to build a script that will log off user from their windows computer by username.
All users are field staff and there AD account is connected to one domain.

What I'm currently doing, I'm remotely logging in to their pc via Connectwise and logging them off and disable to their AD account in exchange server.

Majority of the script I found required to provide computer name or ip address.
Is this possible?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many computers you have in your domain, you could also use the Get-ADComputer commandlet using an operating system filter and then store the results in a variable object. Then use a ForEach to loop through checking each workstation to see if the user is logged in and if found initiate a log off of that user using the example code you already found.
Something like this:

```
$Workstations = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"}
ForEach($Workstation In $Workstations){
#Check to see if user is logged in and if so, log the user off
}
```

Comment: We have over 200 field staff employees on windows 10 machine, can I log off user ONLY by username?

Comment: In order to initiate a logoff on a Windows Workstation you have to be able to provide to PowerShell a set of machines for which to connect to. I do not know of a way to log off a user without that. You may be able to invalidate a logon from the domain controller but that would not actually log out the user on their workstation.